# karma running angular test works on Chrome browser but not on PhantomJs

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm running unit tests in my angular project, and this works fine if I run it with Chrome but, not so much and I use PhantomJS

I have a karma.config.js file like this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'lib/*.js',
        'web/js/*.js',
        'test/spec/*spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],

    // the default configuration
    junitReporter: {
        outputFile: 'testResult/test-results.xml',
        suite: ''
    },



    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true
});
};
```

and like this (with Chrome) works

```
 Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
 INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
 INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
 INFO [Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket oi7YLBSbpVbZSiVI_BPs
 Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 7): Executed 8 of 8 SUCCESS (0.238 secs / 0.019 secs)
```

but if I change the browser (to PhantomJS) gives an error

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket Uy390TQWuDGR2pCi_GRy
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) ERROR
TypeError: '[object NodeList]' is not a valid argument for 
'Function.prototype.apply' (evaluating 'push.apply')
at C:/Users/Lino Simões/Documents/bitbucket/jenkins-test/lib/angular.js: 2594
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.131 secs / 0 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Used --force, continuing.
```

so my question is, why does this work with `Chrome` but not with `PhantomJs` and what can I change to make it work with `PhantomJS`

Comment: Which version of angular.js are you using?

Comment: angular-1.3.0-beta.13

Comment: It's fixed in beta.14, try upgrading! See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7851)

Comment: I upgraded to the last version in [angular-1.3.0-beta.16.js](https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: You should post your own answer (or @runTarm should) that it's fixed in the latest version of Angular. Also more details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7851) if anyone's curious. Then open a new question if you need help w/the new error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'[object NodeList]' is not a valid argument` issue, when running in PhantomJS 1.x, is already fixed in angular.js `v1.3.0-beta.14`, see [#7851](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7851)

Try upgrading the angular.js to `v1.3.0-beta.14` or newer.

PS. Another solution would be using PhantomJS 2